# How To Limit Max Execution Time for Java App from Command Line

Tags: java, limit

How do I limit the maximum execution time when executing a java app from command line, like this:

> java -Xmx10G -cp /weka/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t
>   /test/test-vector.arff -d /test/test.model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built into Java to do this for you. Options:

- Write a wrapper class which launches the original class but *also* creates a timer thread to kill the current process if it hasn't finished in time.
- Use the operating system capabilities

As an example of the latter, in bash on Unix-like systems you could use [`ulimit -t [seconds]`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) before starting the process.

EDIT: As noted in comments, it's not clear how graceful such a shutdown with ulimit would be - whether the threads would be killed in a sufficiently polite way to allow finally blocks to execute etc. That's probably something worth testing out.

EDIT: Again as per comments, ulimit limits the CPU time, not the overall wall time. This may or may not be what you're after - it depends if your process is CPU-bound.

Comment: using ulimit might turn off the application without giving it the chance to gracefully shut down.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: Possibly. I don't know offhand whether it attempts a graceful shutdown first with sigterm, or how Java would handle that. It would be worth testing that out...

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, when you specify a time limit to ulimit that time limit reffers to CPU time, not actual time.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: That's true. Will edit again. It may still be appropriate, but the OP will need to decide. If it *is* appropriate (and if he's using Linux etc) it's probably the simplest approach. But if it's not, it won't :)

Comment: To the OP: I'm not begging for a vote here, in fact if possible please don't vote me at all. But really, if you're coding in Java do it the Java way and make your time limitation in Java as well. You already have a library that does just that, it will work the same way across any OS and you won't mix and match multiple languages for no reason.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: I'm not sure I agree. If the OP definitely only needs the functionality which is already provided (and is on an appropriate OS) why create the wrapper? Writing code to separate the command line parameters for the wrapper vs the parameters for the class being started, handling interruptions etc is work that simply may not need to be done. If the OP has broader requirements than that's fine - but I wouldn't dogmatically rebuild this functionality in Java just for the sake of purism.

Comment: Yes, that's true if the other option was that wrapper you proposed. However doing it with a simple scheduler requires very few extra code. You do need to pass it the cmd line args for shutdown time, but that's it, you dont need to do any interruption handling etc. Also the scheduler proposiotion actually does what the OP asked, namely shuts down the app after a given time, not after some CPU time, which, especially on a multi-CPU machine where the thread/process might be passed from one core to another is completly unreliable like the ulimit would do. Java code is more maintainable then bash.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: What I called a "wrapper" is what you've called a "scheduler". It's something which will launch an arbitrary other class, and schedule shutdown. It may well only be a page of code - but if that's a page of code you don't need to write, why do so? If ulimit does everything the OP wants, why not use it? It's good to have alternative options, but I'd go with the simplest approach that works.

Comment: "What I called a "wrapper" is what you've called a "scheduler"" - no, you're approach seems a lot more complicated then mine from how you describe it. " If ulimit does everything the OP wants, why not use it? "- because it doesn't as you yourself admited afterwards."I'd go with the simplest approach that works." - that approach doesn't work, and having mixed and matched code, that is not compiler checked, and needs some extra stepts to deploy/install is not simpler.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: I said "create a timer thread" - you gave links to `java.util.Timer`. They're equivalent. I would probably use `Timer` as the implementation of creating a timer thread. It doesn't really matter - it's an implementation detail. And ulimit *does* work *if it does what the OP wants*. We haven't heard back from the OP to say exactly what the requirements are, but if limiting CPU time is good enough, I still believe it's the simplest approach. It's *at least* worth considering as an option.

Comment: Sir, I think we've discussed our points for long enough. Anyone intrested in the minute details of what we've said here can read all the comments and draw a conclusion. Thank you for the input!

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: Yes, that was my conclusion too. I think agreeing to disagree is the best course of action. There are pros and cons to both approaches, certainly.

Comment: Looks like both solutions work, but to be honest the first is quicker to implement. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can user Java's scheduler to have it shut down the application after a certain time:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html